# Matrix log norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

How is it that the matrix log norm:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}={||I+\epsilon A||-1\over \epsilon}$$
is equal to $$\max\left( \lambda \left({A+A^T\over 2}\right)\right)$$ (the biggest eigenvalue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $A = B + C$ where $B = (A+A^t)/2$ is symmetric and $C= (A-A^t)/2$ is antisymmetric. We have $I + \epsilon A = \exp (\epsilon A) + O(\epsilon^2)$. Now

$$ \exp \epsilon A = \exp \epsilon(B+C) = (\exp \epsilon B) (\exp \epsilon C) + O(\epsilon^2) = (I + \epsilon B) \exp \epsilon C + O(\epsilon^2)$$

where the second equality follows from the series for $\exp$. The exponential of the skew symmetric matrix $\epsilon C$ is orthogonal. Hence

$$ I + \epsilon A =  (I + \epsilon B)X_\epsilon + O(\epsilon^2) $$

for some orthogonal matrix $X_\epsilon$.
Since $X_\epsilon$ is an isometry, $||(I + \epsilon B)X_\epsilon|| = ||I + \epsilon B||$. But $B$ is real symmetric, so diagonalizable by an orthogonal matrix. We can therefore assume that $B$ is diagonal, and its now clear that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{||I+\epsilon A||-1}{\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{|| I + \epsilon B||-1}{\epsilon}$$

is the largest eigenvalue of $B = (A+A^t)/2$, as required.